# node:_http_outgoing:862 issue in node js... fs not working

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node.js-fs

1. the terminal is showing >>>

node:_http_outgoing:862
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received undefined
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at write_ (node:_http_outgoing:862:11)
at ServerResponse.write (node:_http_outgoing:827:15)
at ReadFileContext.callback (c:\Users\me\Documents\Web Devolopment Challenge\intro\sample-server.js:7:9)
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (node:fs:324:13) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v18.14.1

this is my code

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(7000);
```

and this is my html code

```
<html>
    <h1>hello guys</h1>
    <h2>heyy</h2>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not checking `err`

Answer (score 0):

res.write(data) -- problem lies here in this data(arg).If you are getting  this data from any function,then you may have forgotten to return the fun res.In my case I missed it,so I was getting the same error.So,check it and do the needful.Hope it works.